# Cannot display inline images in HTML using Gmail API with RoR?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, gmail-api, inline-images, incoming-mail

Im building a webmail client in RoR and using Gmail's API.

After receiving a response from Gmail's api for a multipart email, I was able to extract the text/html portion and display it in the browser correctly. Everything looks fine except all of the images are broken.

Upon inspecting the HTML, it shows `<img src="cid:google_logo">`. I understand that this is an inline image referencing the actual image from the attachments. But where and how do I load the attachments into the browser?

I've been looking everywhere and I cannot find a solution. Please help...

Comment: Your google link shows unauthorized error. Host somewhere else

Comment: Look through the parts you get back from the response. Try using something like pry debugger so you can step through the response and inspect it. Off the top of my head there are parts with mimetype image/png or image/jpeg .. etc.. also there maybe a multipart mimetype.