# Gmail api displaying inline images with php

Tags: php, html, image, gmail-api

I am building a application that fetches messages and displays emails from gmail using the php version of the gmail-api.

I am having an issue displaying emails that contain inline images. I get "cid:google_logo net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME" when I check the console. I have learnt that the cid:google_logo is referencing the image that is retrieved as an attachment. But how do I connect the image tag and and the separate attachment.

I am able to download the image from the attachment using php. Therefore I believe that I can change the image source in the html to reference the image i download on the server. But I am wondering if there is an easier way to directly link the html and the attachment from the gmail api.

I have looked at similar question:
[Cannot display inline images in HTML using Gmail API with RoR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30144192/cannot-display-inline-images-in-html-using-gmail-api-with-ror)
and the resource provided in that question:
[Strategies for serving Base64 encoded images in HTML](https://www.codementor.io/tips/8112473532/strategies-for-serving-base64-encoded-images-in-html?new_tips=true)

However even as I tried replacing the following sample with my own encoded attachment data with my own. I am not able to produce a functioning image.

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAYAAACNbyblAAAAHElEQVQI12P4//8/w38GIAXDIBKE0DHxgljNBAAO9TXL0Y4OHwAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" alt="Red dot" />
```

Comment: can you provide some code snippets to have a better understanding of the issue?

Comment: did you get the solution of this ?